# Using gsub replacement with regex

Tags: r, regex

I want to replace a string with "*s*" with "'s_" but only if it has more than one letter to start with.

e.g

If the input is "john_s_fingerprinting", the output should be "john's_fingerprinting". But if the input is "j_s_fingerprinting" then its should not change.

I have tried regex to match that strictly more than one letter criteria but having issue with replacement regex.
Here is what I have so far

```
gsub("[a-z]{2,}_s_", "[a-z]{2,}'s_", "john_s_fingerprinting")
```

The replacement `"[a-z]{2,}'s_"` is not giving me the correct output

Answer (score 2):

We may need to capture as group and replace with backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
gsub("([A-Za-z]{2,})_s", "\\1's", str1)
```

-output

```
[1] "john's_fingerprinting" "j_s_fingerprinting"
```

---

Or another option is a regex lookaround

```
gsub("(?<=[A-Za-z]{2})_s", "'s", str1, perl = TRUE)
[1] "john's_fingerprinting" "j_s_fingerprinting"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("john_s_fingerprinting", "j_s_fingerprinting")
```